# How to use exclude the analysis of all other language and do analysis for required one in sonarQube

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, sonarqube5.1

I am using SonarQube 5.1.2 and maven 3.0.4.I run sonar analysis for one of my project and it gives me all the result.But the issue is it is showing the analysis for all the languages and I need only for Java.Is there a way we can exclude other and keep only java

Current analysis is[image]

Answer (score 1):

Property `sonar.language` is what you're looking for, see [Analysis Parameters](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)

Comment: I used this property to analysis but it is not working in my case <sonar.language>java,grvy</sonar.langugae>

Comment: Is the `langugae` just a typo or is it like that in the properties file too ? Please attach the analysis logs to your initial question.

Comment: Below is the error.I was using property  <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>                                   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project ClinicalDataAcquisition: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'java,grvy' -> [Help 1]
23:34:08 [ERROR] 
23:34:08 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
23:34:08 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: I think these plugin are already in place because if I don't provide this it does the analysis for all languages